# HTML input error message looks ugly on iOS. How to style it?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I'd like to use native HTML5 input properties (like `required` or `pattern`) to have front-end validation of a form. It works fine except on iOS, where error message is not properly aligned to the container (the "bubble"). I was sure it's related to my CSS, but when running the page with zero styling and scripting it still looks ugly.

For instance, [the simplest example of `required` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required#Example) looks like this:

[image: a simplest example of required on MDN run on iOS emulator]

It seems really weird that default solutions on iOS look so terrible. Safari on macOS seems to display it correctly:

[image: a simplest example of required on MDN run on macOS]

I've found that there are some special Webkit-related CSS selectors and I tried to apply them, but it seems like new Safari versions don't take those styles into account:

```
    ::-webkit-validation-bubble-message {
        color: red;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

What can I do to make it look properly?

Comment: Since it's apple, the only thing you can do is report the bug via the apple bugreporter, and maybe possibly it could be they'll read it

Comment: Hi, I faced the same issue. Did you solve the problem?